# NextJS 13 - Error occurred prerendering page "/". (App Directory)

Tags: next.js13

When i type "npm run build" in the terminal, i'm getting an "Error occurred prerendering page "/""

I notice that the problem is about fetching data to my api route. But I cant figure out why it is causing error when building. It works fine when I run in npm run dev. But in build it errors.

File Location: /src/app/page.tsx

```
import TopicsList from "@/components/TopicsList";
import { Suspense } from "react";
import Loading from "./loading";
export default async function Home() {
  

  return (
    <>
      <h1>Topic</h1>
      <Suspense fallback={<Loading />}>
        <TopicsList />
      </Suspense>
    </>
  );
}
```

File Location of TopicList : /src/components/TopicList.tsx

```
import RemoveBtn from "./RemoveBtn";
import Link from "next/link";
import { HiPencilAlt } from "react-icons/hi";
import { TopicProps } from "@/models/definitions";


export default async function  TopicsList() {
    
    const response = await fetch("http://localhost:3000/api/topics", { cache: "no-store"})
    const data = await response.json()
    const { topics } = data
    return(
        <>
           { topics.map((topic: TopicProps) => {
                return (
                    <div key={topic._id} className="border border-slate-700 p-4 flex justify-between mb-4 items-start">
                        <div>
                            <h1 className="font-bold text-2xl">{topic.topicTitle}</h1>
                            <p>{topic.topicDescription}</p>
                        </div>
                        <div className="flex gap-2">
                            <RemoveBtn id={topic._id}  />
                            <Link href={`/editTopic/${topic._id}`}>
                                <HiPencilAlt size={24}/>
                            </Link>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                )
           })}
        </>
    )
}
```

api route: /src/app/api/route.ts

```
import connectMongoDB from "@/libs/mongodb";
import Topic from "@/models/topic";
import { NextRequest, NextResponse } from "next/server";


export async function GET(request: NextRequest) {
    await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 3000));
    await connectMongoDB();
    const topics = await Topic.find();
    return NextResponse.json({topics}, {status: 200})
}
```